# localhost te redireccionó demasiadas veces. Laravel Middelware

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un sistema en donde el usuario que se loguea por primera vez debe cambiar su contraseña obligatoriamente.
Para eso cree un campo en la base de datos llamado cambio_pass para controlar. Luego cree un middelware para verificar que el usuario haya cambiado o no su contraseña.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Auth::user()->cambio_pass == 1) {
      return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('cambiar_contrasena');
}
```

Luego este middelware lo agregue a mis rutas

```
    Route::get('/home', function () {
            return redirect('/puntajes');
        });

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'cambio_pass'], function () {

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return redirect('/puntajes');
        });

        Route::get('/puntajes', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::get('/extracto', 'ClienteController@extracto');
        Route::get('/historial', 'ClienteController@historial');
        Route::get('/historial_mes/{id}', 'ClienteController@historial_mes');
        Route::get('/transferencia/', 'TransferenciaController@index');
        Route::post('/transferencia/enviar', 'TransferenciaController@transferir');
        Route::get('/catalogo/', 'CatalogoController@index');
        Route::post('/canjear_producto', 'CatalogoController@canjear_producto');
        Route::get('/bases', function () {
            return view('informativo.bases');
        });
        Route::get('/acumula_mas', function () {
            return view('informativo.acumula_mas');
        });
        Route::get('/cambiar_contrasena', 'PassController@index');
        Route::post('/cambiar_pass', 'PassController@store');
    });
});
```

Se que estoy redireccionando mucho mi sitio pero no se que otra forma puedo hacer el cambio obligatorio de contraseña.. alguna ayuda?

Comment: Te deje una respuesta, revisalo y dime si te sirvió, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu ruta **"/cambiar_contrasena"** se encuentra dentro del Middleware **"cambio_pass"**, tienes que sacarlo fuera de ese Middleware para que ya no exista el loop de redirección.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'cambio_pass'], function () {

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return redirect('/puntajes');
        });

        Route::get('/puntajes', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::get('/extracto', 'ClienteController@extracto');
        Route::get('/historial', 'ClienteController@historial');
        Route::get('/historial_mes/{id}', 'ClienteController@historial_mes');
        Route::get('/transferencia/', 'TransferenciaController@index');
        Route::post('/transferencia/enviar', 'TransferenciaController@transferir');
        Route::get('/catalogo/', 'CatalogoController@index');
        Route::post('/canjear_producto', 'CatalogoController@canjear_producto');
        Route::get('/bases', function () {
            return view('informativo.bases');
        });
        Route::get('/acumula_mas', function () {
            return view('informativo.acumula_mas');
        });            
    });
    Route::get('/cambiar_contrasena', 'PassController@index');
    Route::post('/cambiar_pass', 'PassController@store');
});
```

Comment: me funciono.. muchas gracias